# store dropdown name and value on database

Tags: php, select

I am trying to put into my database not just the value or number of the selected option but also the name of the option itself like in this case Butter Salmon... Like for example: If I choose option value 1, I want the value 1 to be inserted in my data base and also the name of the product which is Butter Salmon to a diff column.

```
<select type="text" id="buttersalmon_quantity" name="bsalmon" size="1" value="Butter Salmon" >
<option value="0" selected >quantity</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>    
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<?php 
include('./config/connect.php');


if(@$_POST['yourname'] == "")
{
echo "Please enter your name";
} 
else{

$yourname = $_POST['yourname'];
$bsalmon = $_POST['bsalmon'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ralphjoy`.`tbl_cart` (`yourname`, `prd`)VALUES('$yourname','$bsalmon') ") 
or die ("Query Error");

echo "<script>alert('YOUR ORDERS WERE SENT TO THE COUNTER. IT WILL BE SERVE IN A FEW
MINUTES. THANK YOU.')</script>";}   
?>
```

Comment: "Butter Salmon" will not be sent by the browser (select value), but "bsalmon" will (select name). You need to look it up elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a bind, you can do something like this.

```
<select type="text" id="buttersalmon_quantity" name="bsalmon" size="1" value="Butter Salmon" >
    <option value="0" selected >quantity</option>
    <option value="1||Buttered Salmon">1</option>
```

Continue the above for all quantities, using the quantity and the name delimited by an unusual character that will absolutely not typically appear in the value. This will be the delimiter for our explode and it's necessary that it not be a string or character that appears normally in the value.

Then, in your PHP, do something like the following:

```
$bsalmon = explode('||', $_POST['bsalmon']);
$bsalmon_quant = $bsalmon[0];
$bsalmon_name = $bsalmon[1];
```

You'll now have the quantity (`$bsalmon_quant`) to be inserted in one column and the name (`$bsalmon_name` [`Butter Salmon`]) to be inserted into another.

Remove the value from your select tag, though, it's doing nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your html value include both the number and name with some sort of delimiter, like "|" or something, e.g. `<option value="1|buttersalmon_quantity">1</option>` You will need to add this to each and every option line.  Then in your php explode on the delimiter and you have your two values to put into the data base.